# overlaying images with GDI+

Tags: gdi+, overlay

I'm trying to overlay a image with a couple of other images. I use this code to do that:

```
Dim gbkn As Bitmap = New Bitmap(7001, 7001, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(CType(gbkn, Image))
g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("C:\background.png"), New Point(0, 0))
g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("C:\firstlayer.png"), New Point(0, 0))
g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("C:\secondlayer.png"), New Point(0, 0))
```

This works with the first two pictures. After that an OutOfMemoryException is thrown.
I realize the size of the images are large. 
But isn't it somehow possible to do the overlays and chache them somewhere?

Even if I save the result of the first overlay to disk, free memory, and add another layer I still get the exception.

How should I approach this problem?

JosP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is actually the problem, but you are not disposing of the images that you are drawing on the bitmap.  Does this help?

```
Dim gbkn As Bitmap = New Bitmap(7001, 7001, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(CType(gbkn, Image))
Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\background.png")
g.DrawImage(img, New Point(0, 0))
img.Dipose()
img As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\firstlayer.png")
g.DrawImage(img, New Point(0, 0))
img.Dispose()
img As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\secondlayer.png")
g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("C:\secondlayer.png"), New Point(0, 0))
img.Dispose()
```

I seriously doubt it has anything to do with the images, as I have worked with images 2-3 times that size without that problem.  Also OutOfMemoryError exception seems to be one of the <sarcasm>extremely useful</sarcasm> errors that GDI throws that frequently has nothing to do with memory.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the first empty bitmap? Without it, you allocate only 3*200 MB instead of 4*200 MB, perhaps this will work:

```
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage("C:\background.png")
g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("C:\firstlayer.png"), New Point(0, 0))
// and so on
```

It's strange that overlaying in several steps doesn't work, I think you're not freeing memory correctly in this case. Perhaps it will be better to post the code you're using for this approach.

I also assume that you do need the original images somewhere else or do specifically want to do this using C#/GDI+, as it would be very easy to merge the PNG files using some image editing programs.

Comment: The first empty is only there because the Graphics-object can not be instantiated from an indexed image format.

Comment: Between the several steps I tried calling the Dispose method on the Graphics-object right after calling the DrawImage method. I even tried saving the intermediate results to disk and then loading them back again. Doesn't help. Still get the exception on the third image that I overlay. 
For this I use consecutive calls to the code snippet beneath:
            
    gbkn = Image.FromFile("c:\_1.bmp")
    g = Graphics.FromImage(gbkn)
    g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(mstrPNGs(1)), New Point(0, 0))
    gbkn.Dispose()
    g.Dispose()

Comment: And yes, the PNG files can not be merged by another program beforehand. It has to be done in this program

And thanks a lot for helping! Been feeling very alone on this the last couple of days...